# Полнотекстный поиск по типу LIKE или NEAR с плэйсхолдером

Tags: php, mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Поиск выводит только полное совпадение в ячейке, не могу найти как искачь по части иекста (например 4-5 символов и чтобы нашло все ячейки в которых есть такие символы) пример: в плэйсхолдер вводим "pan" находит все ячейки с "pan", "panika" и т.д.

запрос на обработку:

```
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sandoz` WHERE MATCH (AssetType, AssetSubtype, UniqID, Asset_Status, SN, CR_IMEI) AGAINST ('". $_POST["search"] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Структура таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `sandoz` (
  `Inventory_LLC` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `Inventory_DD` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `AssetCategory` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `AssetType` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `AssetSubtype` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Transfer_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Return_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `UniqID` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Asset_Owner` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Owner_Comp` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Owner_Location` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Owner_Status` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Asset_Status` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Asset_Entity` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `SN` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Notes` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `CR_IMEI` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Org_Unit` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Position` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Cost` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Any_Val` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Pur_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Check_Uncheck` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `Local_Material` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `PO` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Activated` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin;

ALTER TABLE `sandoz`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SN`),
  ADD KEY `SN` (`SN`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `SN_2` (`SN`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `AssetType` (`AssetType`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `AssetSubtype` (`AssetSubtype`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `UniqID` (`UniqID`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `Asset_Status` (`Asset_Status`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `CR_IMEI` (`CR_IMEI`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: все зависит от того, как и что вы хотите искать...

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis например ввод 3-4 символов для поиска серийного номера в таблице, когда сам серийник состоит из 12+ символов, в общем как LIKE только через парсер

Comment: @Akina я юзаю mySQL, случайно не тот тег поставил

Comment: В таком случае NEAR неприменим, он не из этой деревни. В MySQL существует только `MATCH .. AGAINST`, всё остальное рулится режимами поиска. Ваша задача (поиск по префиксу) в принципе реализуема в Boolean Mode - но это из пушки по воробьям. LIKE гораздо более подходящий инструмент.

Comment: @Akina если через LIKE делать то сильно повышается время поиска (база довольно большая) так что не очень хотелось бы :(

Comment: Ну тогда читайте [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: @Akina почитал всякие ресурсы, попробовал разные варианты не ищет оно так(

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте свой вопрос, и вместо абстрактной хотелки покажите пример исходных данных (несколько имеющихся записей), условия поиска (2-3 шаблона), и указания, какие из записей должны вернуться для каждого шаблона и почему.

Comment: @Akina отредактировал вопрос, надеюсь так понятнее что я хочу)

Comment: TL;DR Отредактируйте ещё раз и выбросите всю HTML/PHP обвязку, оставив только MySQL структуры, данные и код.

Comment: @Akina вот все кроме SQL убрал

Comment: 1) Вы оставили кусок PHP. Покажите результат сборки $sql, а не код этой сборки. 2) Ваши индексы непригодны для поиска показанным запросом. См. [Full-Text Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html) *The MATCH() column list **must match exactly** the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table, unless this MATCH() is IN BOOLEAN MODE on a MyISAM table.* А у Вас движок InnoDB.

Comment: @Akina все я понял, не тот движок базы

Comment: Только не базы, а таблицы.